# Sleuth in Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-cloud-sleuth

Hi I am new to Apache Camel, but in my application our team implemented this in so many places. Now we are migrating existing came implemented application to Micro services, here we are not finding any option to implement Spring cloud Sleuth with existing camel implemented service, any solution?

Comment: you can use or take example from https://github.com/Playtika/sleuth-camel

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing there out of the box. You would have to create such a tracing implementation yourself.